# How to generate random dates between date range inside pandas column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df that looks like this

```
df:

id   dob
1    7/31/2018
2    6/1992
```

I want to generate 88799 random dates to go into column `dob` in the dataframe, between the dates of `1960-01-01` to `1990-12-31` while keeping the format `mm/dd/yyyy` no time stamp.

How would I do this?

I tried:

```
date1 = (1960,01,01)
date2 = (1990,12,31)

for i range(date1,date2):
    df.dob = i
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would figure out how many days are in your date range, then select 88799 random integers in that range, and finally add that as a timedelta with `unit='d'` to your minimum date:

```
min_date = pd.to_datetime('1960-01-01')
max_date = pd.to_datetime('1990-12-31')

d = (max_date - min_date).days + 1

df['dob'] = min_date + pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.random.randint(d,size=88799), unit='d')

>>> df.head()
         dob
0 1963-03-05
1 1973-06-07
2 1970-08-24
3 1970-05-03
4 1971-07-03

>>> df.tail()
             dob
88794 1965-12-10
88795 1968-08-09
88796 1988-04-29
88797 1971-07-27
88798 1980-08-03
```

**EDIT** You can format your dates using `.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`, but note that this will slow down the execution significantly:

```
df['dob'] = (min_date + pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.random.randint(d,size=88799), unit='d')).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

>>> df.head()
          dob
0  02/26/1969
1  04/09/1963
2  08/29/1984
3  02/12/1961
4  08/02/1988
>>> df.tail()
              dob
88794  02/13/1968
88795  02/05/1982
88796  07/03/1964
88797  06/11/1976
88798  11/17/1965
```

Comment: Could use `strftime` to format the date as OP asked

Comment: @sacul thank you, how could I format the date on the fly ?

Comment: @sacuL. Could I please check a couple of points? In the line pd.np.random.randint do we need to include the pd.np.random.randint or could we just write np.random.randint? I couldn't see any difference in my result when I included the pd. or not. Also for the line d = (max_date - min_date).days + 1, can you explain the use of .days here? I understand that we are using days as a unit of time (hence unit='d' later in the code) however I don't fully understand why I need to include .days here as d is just a max integer value for randint? My code fails if I don't include it. Many thanks

Comment: @mmTmmR `pd.np.random.randint` is there just so you don't have to explicitly import numpy by `import numpy as np`, but it is exactly the same as saying `np.random.randint` *if* you have imported numpy already. For the `d = (max_date - min_date).days + 1`, that is just to get a list of valid integers. `.days` gives an integer of the number of days in the range `max_date - min_date`